# Filling Missing Values Based on String Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I'm trying to write a function to impute some null values from a Numeric column based on string conditions from a Text column.

My attempt example:

```
def fill_nulls(string, val):
if df['TextColumn'].str.contains(string) == True:
    df['NumericColumn'] = df['NumericColumn'].fillna(value=val)
```

The 'string' and 'val' parameters are manually entered. I tried applying function to my numeric column but it gives me this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I tried to find examples that I could tweak for my situation, but they all involved using 'groupby' to get the average numeric values relating to the discrete string values that had only a handful of unique values. Basically, only exact wording could be imputed, whereas I'm trying to generalize my string filtering by using partial strings and **imputing the null values in the numeric column** based on the **resulting rows of the text columns**.

Comment: Could you give an example of usage... for instance are you running this multiple times with different strings and values, eg: `find_nulls('bob', 1)` and then `find_nulls('fred', 2)` etc... or...?

Comment: Hi, yes I am going to run this with multiple strings and values until all the nulls are filled. So, like say you have a text column that has a lot of variations like "Install ABC components", "Install Components", "Install ABC"... I just want to do a lookup for "Install" get the average numeric column values for the resulting rows from the string lookup, and impute the missing values using those. And yeah, like using .apply and fill_nulls('install', 2.6) on the numeric column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df['TextColumn'].str.contains(string)
df.loc[m, 'NumericColumn'] = df.loc[m, 'NumericColumn'].fillna(value=val)
```

Or chain conditions by `&` for bitwise `AND` for test missing values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and assign value in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m1 = df['TextColumn'].str.contains(string)
m2 = df['NumericColumn'].isna()
df.loc[m1 & m2, 'NumericColumn'] = val
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks!! I like this one because it uses "str.contains". I didn't know you can use element-wise operations to set the condition in the first element, and apply it to the column in the second element like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
x = df['TextColumn'].map(lambda x: x.contains(string))
df['NumericColumn'][x] = df['NumericColumn'][x].fillna(value=val)
```

First you generate the list of elements you want to replace with the map, then use that list to replace elements you want to replace.

edit: fixed typo in code

Comment: This kind of looks like it'll do what I'm trying to do! I'll give it a shot tomorrow and report back with results!